# Come down faster after jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

In my 2D game, I need my player to be able to pull down after jumping. I tried using a vertical control on the joystick, but it just made me float around. When I try to jump, I hang in the air too long. 
  I want to be able to pull my player downward. How is there a way to get that kind of movement without input.getkeydown? Here is the code :

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool facingRight = true;         // For determining which way the player is currently facing.
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool jump = false;               // Condition for whether the player should jump.
    public float moveForce = 365f;          // Amount of force added to move the player left and right.
    public float maxSpeed = 5f;             // The fastest the player can travel in the x axis.
    public float jumpForce = 1000f;// Amount of force added when the player jumps.
    public string jumpButton = "Jump_P1";
    public string horizontalCtrl = "Horizontal_P1";
    public string verticalCtrl = "Vertical_P1";


    private Transform groundCheck;          // A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
    private bool grounded = false;          // Whether or not the player is grounded.


    void Awake()
    {
        // Setting up references.
        groundCheck = transform.Find("groundCheck");

    }

    void Update(){
        // The player is grounded if a linecast to the groundcheck position hits anything on the ground layer.
        grounded = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, groundCheck.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));  

        // If the jump button is pressed and the player is grounded then the player should jump.
        if(Input.GetButtonDown(jumpButton) && grounded)
            jump = true;
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Cache the horizontal input.
        float h = Input.GetAxis (horizontalCtrl);
        float a = Input.GetAxis (verticalCtrl);


        // If the player is changing direction (h has a different sign to velocity.x) or hasn't reached maxSpeed yet...
        if (h * GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x < maxSpeed)
            // ... add a force to the player.
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (Vector2.right * h * moveForce);

        // If the player's horizontal velocity is greater than the maxSpeed...
        if (Mathf.Abs (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x) > maxSpeed)
            // ... set the player's velocity to the maxSpeed in the x axis.
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (Mathf.Sign (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x) * maxSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y);

        // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
        if (h > 0 && !facingRight)
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip ();
        // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
        else if (h < 0 && facingRight)
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip ();

        // If the player should jump...
        if (jump) {

            // Add a vertical force to the player.
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (new Vector2 (0f, jumpForce));

            // Make sure the player can't jump again until the jump conditions from Update are satisfied.
            jump = false;
        }
    }

    void Flip ()
    {
        // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
        facingRight = !facingRight;

        // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

Comment: add rigid-body to your player

Comment: My player has a rigid-body; When I jump he just kind of floats down.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the gravity on your player's `RigidBody2D` while also increasing the `jumpForce` variable so that he jumps high enough. With the increased gravity and jump force, he can jump as high as he can now and then the gravity will send him back to the ground quickly.